# How to return type char from function pointer in c

Tags: c, string, char, function-pointers, return-type

Wrote the following code that takes the time input from a struct and prints it all together into a string:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct time
{
    int hour;                                       
    int minute;                                     
    char am_pm [3];                                 
    char (*standard_time)(struct time *self);
};

char standard_time_format(struct time *self)
{
    char standard_format[8], conversion[3];
    int length;

    length = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", self->hour);
    snprintf(conversion, length + 1, "%d", self->hour);
    strcpy(standard_format, conversion);

    strcat(standard_format, ":");

    length = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", self->minute);
    snprintf(conversion, length + 1, "%d", self->minute);
    strcat(standard_format, conversion);

    strcat(standard_format, self->am_pm);

    return(standard_format);
}

int  main()
{
    struct time start;
    char standard_format[8];

    start.hour = 2;
    start.minute = 34;
    strcpy(start.am_pm, "am");
    start.standard_time = standard_time_format;

    strcpy(standard_format, start.standard_time(&start));
    printf("%s\n", standard_format);

    return 0;
}
```

However, it is unable to print out the result as the return type doesn't seem to be compatible.

Changing types to pointers didn't fix it either:

in the struct:

```
char *(*standard_time)(struct time *self);
```

the function:

```
char *standard_time_format(struct time *self)
```

and in both routines creating a pointer to standard_format:

```
char *str = &standard_format;
```

and returning the pointer in the function:

```
return(str);
```

**So what type exactly is being returned, and how can it be accessed properly to display it in the printf command?**

**EDIT**

As suggested in the answers, I modified the code such that a string was passed as an argument to the function instead, which remedied the issue. The following is the updated code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct time
{
    int hour;
    int minute;
    char am_pm [3];
    void (*standard_time)(struct time *self, char standard_format[8]);
};

void standard_time_format(struct time *self, char standard_format[8])
{
    char conversion[3];

    snprintf(conversion, sizeof(conversion), "%d", self->hour);
    strcpy(standard_format, conversion);

    strcat(standard_format, ":");

    snprintf(conversion, sizeof(conversion), "%d", self->minute);
    strcat(standard_format, conversion);

    strcat(standard_format, self->am_pm);
}

int  main()
{
    struct time start;
    char standard_format[8];

    start.hour = 2;
    start.minute = 34;
    strcpy(start.am_pm, "am");
    start.standard_time = standard_time_format;

    start.standard_time(&start, standard_format);
    printf("%s\n", standard_format);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't return pointers to local (stack-allocated) variables.

Comment: in `snprintf(conversion, length + 1` you maybe write out of bounds - the second argument should be the size of the buffer

Comment: Thanks  :)  just realized there's no need for "int length" in this, and it should be "snprintf(conversion, sizeof(conversion) . . ."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `standard_time_format` function when you do

```
return(standard_format);
```

you attempt to return a pointer to the first element in the array `standard_format` (remember that arrays *decays* to pointers to its first element, i.e. `&standard_format[0]`). Its type is `char *`.

***However*** this is very problematic since `standard_format` is a *local variable* inside the function, and it will go out of scope once the `return` statement have been executed, leaving you with a *dangling pointer* which you can't dereference (attempting to do so will lead to [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)).

The simple and standard solution is to pass the string to be filled as an *argument* to the function.

Answer (score 0):

```
return(standard_format);
```

Here you have returned pointer that points to local variable when `standard_time_format` returns its stack will be deallocated and eventually `standard_format` that you returned will become invalid

You should pass char array to `standard_time_format`  and copy the string that you want to return in it, instead of returning local variable